# Read files using PLSQL from Multipart/Form-data in POST ORDS

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an ORDS POST API where the front end developer will send 2 pdf files in multipart/form-data. I then have to send email with two pdf attachments using UTL_SMTP. I am on Oracle 12.1

I have the below utl smtp proc which can attach blobs in email from a table and it works fine by calling multiple times.But, I am not able to make it work when I have to read the files coming from multipart/form-data in POST API.
How should I read the form-data files?

```
....
...
    PROCEDURE multiple_attachment( p_conn       IN OUT utl_smtp.connection
                                     ,p_boundary   IN VARCHAR2
                                     ,p_FileName   IN VARCHAR2
                                     ,p_FileData   IN BLOB)
      AS
          l_len       integer := 0 ;
          l_idx       integer := 1 ;
          l_buff_size integer := 57 ;
          l_raw       raw(57) ;
        BEGIN
                  -- Attachment
                utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, '--' || p_boundary || utl_tcp.crlf );
                utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, 'Content-Type: application/pdf' || utl_tcp.crlf );
                utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; ' || utl_tcp.crlf );
                utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, ' filename="' || p_FileName || '"' || utl_tcp.crlf );
                utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.crlf );
                utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, utl_tcp.crlf );

                l_len := dbms_lob.getlength(p_FileData);
    
                l_buff_size := 57 ;
                l_idx := 1;
    
                WHILE l_idx < l_len LOOP
                  dbms_lob.read( p_FileData , l_buff_size, l_idx, l_raw );
                  utl_smtp.write_raw_data( p_conn, utl_encode.base64_encode(l_raw) );
                  utl_smtp.write_data( p_conn, utl_tcp.crlf );
                  l_idx := l_idx + l_buff_size;
                END LOOP;
        END;
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

     ....
     ...
```